# How to save a nested list in XML or User Settings?

Tags: c#, xml, settings, nested-lists

I have a nested list of lists of PictureBox:

```
 List<List<PictureBox>> listaAgrupamentos = new List<List<PictureBox>>();
```

And I want to save that list data either in XML or in User Settings when I close the program but I don't know how.

Comment: Saving a PictureBox is not a good idea. Save the image of the Picturebox instead. Using XML is overkill. A binary format is probably more suitable.

Comment: So how do I do this?

Comment: Xml files usually have the URL of images and not the actual file itself.  There is nothing wrong with a XML file containing a list of URL (images).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a binary fashion using **Image.Save()**:

```
public static void SaveBitmapMatrix(List<List<Bitmap>> bitmapMatrix)
{
  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("ImageContainer.db", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
      binaryWriter.Write(bitmapMatrix.Count);

      foreach (List<Bitmap> bitmaps in bitmapMatrix)
      {
        binaryWriter.Write(bitmaps.Count);

        foreach (Bitmap bitmap in bitmaps)
        {
          long lastPosition = fileStream.Position;
          binaryWriter.Write(0);
          bitmap.Save(fileStream, ImageFormat.Png);
          int length = (int)(fileStream.Position - lastPosition - sizeof(int));
          fileStream.Seek(lastPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
          binaryWriter.Write(length);
          fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First you have to store the length of the outer list. Then for each inner list.  And for each image: Reserve a fixed space of 4 bytes (for the actual image length), save the image, reset the stream position and update the reserved bytes with the calculated length.
Reverse this process and you'll end up with this code:

```
public static List<List<Bitmap>> LoadBitmapMatrix()
{
  List<List<Bitmap>> bitmapMatrix = new List<List<Bitmap>>();

  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("ImageContainer.db", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
    {
      int bitmapMatrixCount = binaryReader.ReadInt32();

      for (int m = 0; m < bitmapMatrixCount; m++)
      {
        int bitmapCount = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        bitmapMatrix.Add(new List<Bitmap>(bitmapCount));

        for (int b = 0; b < bitmapCount; b++)
        {
          int bitmapLength = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
          
          using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(binaryReader.ReadBytes(bitmapLength)))
          {
            bitmapMatrix[m].Add((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(memoryStream));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return bitmapMatrix;
}
```